# How to pick n top values from each column and save the corresponding rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a big data frame where I need to pick 3 top values (the order matters) from each column and save the corresponding row number.

```
names<- c("t1","t10","t11","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9")
values1 <- c(2,3.1,4.5,5.1,6.5,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,11.8,12.3)
values2 <- c(1,3.1,3,5.1,6.5,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,12,12) 

mydf<- data.frame(names,values1,values2)
#@Juan Bosco has suggested  the followings which is great but gets confuses in this case where I have similar values...
idx <- lapply(2:3, function(col_index) { 
max_values <- sort(mydf[[col_index]], decreasing = T)[1:3]
sapply(max_values, function(one_value){
as.numeric(rownames(mydf[mydf[[col_index]] == one_value, ]))
 })
})
```

Any idea how I can tackle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How do you define "highest value"  for the names column?  For the rest, as they are numeric, you can use `max`.

Comment: I can remove that column as long as I can keep track of row numbers. But `max` gives  a single value, right? I want n top ones. @Juan Bosco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following returns the row numbers of the three highest values, using subsetting directly on the results of `sort` in decreasing order, assuming the row names and the row numbers are the same.

```
lapply(2:3, function(col_index) { 
      as.numeric(rownames(mydf[mydf[[col_index]] %in% sort(mydf[[col_index]], decreasing = T)[1:3], ]))
    })
```

**Edit:**

The previous approach returns the row numbers *in no particular order*.

The following addition to the code returns the row numbers with the highest values in order, from the first highest value to the third.

```
lapply(2:3, function(col_index) { 
  max_values <- sort(mydf[[col_index]], decreasing = T)[1:3]
  sapply(max_values, function(one_value){
    as.numeric(rownames(mydf[mydf[[col_index]] == one_value, ]))
  })
})
```

**Edit 2:**

The previous code doesn't deal well with ties. The following is a way to handle ties.

```
lapply(2:3, function(col_index) { 
  max_values <- sort(mydf[[col_index]], decreasing = T)[1:3]
  max_rows <- sapply(max_values, function(one_value){
    as.numeric(rownames(mydf[mydf[[col_index]] == one_value, ]))
  })

  unique(unlist(max_rows))

})
```

This introduces a new problem, you can end with *more than three values for row*. A quick and dirty way to deal with this is selecting the first three values of interest.

```
unique(unlist(max_rows))[1:3]
```

Comment: This works but I need the results to be sorted by value as well not row number which is now. In other words, I want the first highest, second highest and third highest for each column, the order matters. @Juan Bosco

Comment: @Jack I've added an edit that should return the row numbers in order.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Juan Bosco. This is great but it gets confuse when we have two identical values!

Comment: @Jack If you have two values tied for highest value in a column. How would you order them? What rule needs to be followed?

Comment: No rule in that case! Random is fine. although I don't want any smaller value to be selected in that case. So if there are two tied for the highest and we want to select two in total both should be selected in any order. Cheers  @Juan Bosco

Comment: @Jack I've added an edit, that I hope helps you get closer to your goal.
But! It does introduce a new problem, for which I can't figure a good solution.

Comment: Great, That will do. Thanks for your help @Juan Bosco.

Comment: I encountered a new issue in that regard and really appreciate if you can help again @Juan                                                                                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743749/how-to-save-row-names-when-selecting-each-column-independently-instead-of-row-nu